# "Subquery returned more than 1 value" for SELECT subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008. I'm having an issue with writing a subquery. This is the entire query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    FH.ShipDate, AVG(FH.[Dist Freight]) AS [Atlantic Freight Charge], 
    (SELECT DISTINCT [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge]
     FROM 
         (SELECT DISTINCT 
              FH.ShipDate, AVG(FH.[Dist Freight]) AS [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge]
          FROM dbo.vw_FreightHistory AS FH
          WHERE VendorName != 'Atlantic Trucking'
          GROUP BY ShipDate, VendorName) AS [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge])
FROM dbo.vw_FreightHistory as FH
WHERE VendorName = 'Atlantic Trucking'
GROUP BY ShipDate, VendorName
ORDER BY ShipDate
```

The issue first came up when I added that second subquery. The first subquery did not return any errors but it showed the entire average sum of "Dist Freight" in each ShipDate record rather than the average for only that ShipDate. I wrote the second subquery to try and fix that, but now I'm getting this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Please let me know if I should clarify anything.

Comment: Could you show the table structure, some data and give an explanation of what you are trying to do? Like the point of your query. It looks like it could probably be re-written in a simple way if we only knew what you want it to do.

Comment: Not related to your error message, but you appear to be missing a closing bracket.

Comment: @DanBracuk brackets are fine, nothing is missing

Comment: [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge] return several results. You have built average per date, so if you extract average for today and for tomorrow, your DISTINCT [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge] returns 2 result.

Comment: @DavidSöderlund it's a pretty large table but the attributes I'm trying to use are ShipDate, VendorName, and Dist Freight. Basically, what I'm trying to do is show a trend of the average "Dist Freight" cost for one specific VendorName and then the average for all other vendors in another column. The output should be three columns: each distinct ShipDate, the average freight cost for Vendor A on that date, and the average freight cost for all other vendors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
 SELECT 
    FH.ShipDate, 
    AVG(CASE 
           WHEN VendorName = 'Atlantic Trucking' 
           THEN FH.[Dist Freight] 
           ELSE NULL 
        END) AS [Atlantic Freight Charge],  
    AVG(CASE 
           WHEN VendorName != 'Atlantic Trucking' 
           THEN FH.[Dist Freight] 
           ELSE NULL 
         END) AS [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge]
FROM 
    dbo.vw_FreightHistory as FH
GROUP BY 
    ShipDate
ORDER BY 
    ShipDate
```

Comment: Sorry , I corrected my script. NULL should actually be used instead of 0 in the case statement.

Comment: This seems to work beautifully. I didn't know you could use cases in SQL (I'm a pretty basic user), that's really neat. Looks like it just goes through and grabs the average Dist Freight if the name is Atlantic Trucking, and if it's not in the record for that day then it returns Null. Then it does the same for all of the other carriers. Thank you so much!! By the way, do you have any recommendations for websites that teach these more nuanced queries?

Comment: This particular example came from years of writing financial reports and looking at code. For more advanced sql concepts and queries I like this resource here, although it may not necessarily apply in your case: http://www.sommarskog.se/

Comment: Hah, well again I appreciate the input. I'll check that website out.

Comment: Ah, glad to see someone had the same answer I came to, and rather more tersely at that. Martin, I hope my answer at least serves as an explanation of why your query had problems.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you have a subquery returning multiple rows and you're trying to store it as a value in a single row/column combination.

To understand why this is the case, let's look at what the result would look like for the outer query, the 'Atlantic Freight Charge':

### Table 1 - Atlantic Freight Charges

```
ShipDate        Atlantic Freight Charge
01/01/2012      1.00
01/02/2012      1.00
01/03/2012      1.00
01/04/2012      1.00
01/05/2012      1.00
```

And let's look at what the inner subquery might return:

### Table 2 - Non-Atlantic Freight Charges

```
ShipDate        Non-Atlantic Freight Charge
01/01/2012      2.00
01/02/2012      3.00
01/03/2012      4.00
01/04/2012      5.00
01/05/2012      6.00
```

Finally, what do the distinct `Non-Atlantic Freight Charge` rows look like for table 2?

### Table 3 - Distinct Non-Atlantic Freight Charges

```
Non-Atlantic Freight Charge
2.00
3.00
4.00
5.00
6.00
```

Now, in SQL, you are specifying that you want a report with **three columns**, based on your SELECT clause. Here's how that lays out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

  FH.ShipDate

, AVG(FH.[Dist Freight]) AS [Atlantic Freight Charge]

, (SELECT DISTINCT [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge]
    FROM 
      (SELECT DISTINCT FH.ShipDate, AVG(FH.[Dist Freight]) AS [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge]
          FROM dbo.vw_FreightHistory AS FH
          WHERE VendorName != 'Atlantic Trucking'
          GROUP BY ShipDate, VendorName) AS [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge])
```

You see the first column is `ShipDate`, the second column is `Atlantic Freight Charge`, and the third column is a query of **every distinct `Non-Atlantic Freight Charge` from an inner subquery**.

In order for SQL Server to represent this correctly, imagine trying to put the results of that query in the first table.

So for the first row of Table 1:

```
ShipDate        Atlantic Freight Charge
01/01/2012      1.00
```

We need to add a column `Non-Atlantic Freight Charge`, and we need to store in it the results of the query from Table 3:

```
| ShipDate      | Atlantic Freight Charge | Non-Atlantic Freight Charge     |
|---------------|-------------------------|---------------------------------|
| 01/01/2012    | 1.00                    | | Non-Atlantic Freight Charge | |
|               |                         | |-----------------------------| |
|               |                         | | 2.00                        | |
|               |                         | | 3.00                        | |
|               |                         | | 4.00                        | |
|               |                         | | 5.00                        | |
|               |                         | | 6.00                        | |
|               |                         | |-----------------------------| |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

***Uh oh.*** We've got a table, *inside* our table.

That's the problem, we've got one table inside another table!

So there are **two** solutions to your problem. You should evaluate the performance of each.

The first is to use a feature called [Common Table Expressions or CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to run two separate queries and join the results.

That query would look like this:

### CTE Solution

```
;  WITH Atlantic AS (
 SELECT FH.ShipDate, AVG(FH.[Dist Freight]) AS [Atlantic Freight Charge]
   FROM dbo.vw_FreightHistory as FH
  WHERE VendorName = 'Atlantic Trucking'
  GROUP BY ShipDate
      )
      , NonAtlantic AS (
 SELECT FH.ShipDate, AVG(FH.[Dist Freight]) AS [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge]
   FROM dbo.vw_FreightHistory as FH
  WHERE VendorName != 'Atlantic Trucking'
  GROUP BY ShipDate
      )
 SELECT COALESCE(Atlantic.ShipDate, NonAtlantic.ShipDate)
      , ISNULL([Atlantic Freight Charge], 0) AS [Atlantic Freight Charge]
      , ISNULL([Non-Atlantic Freight Charge], 0) AS [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge]
   FROM Atlantic
        FULL OUTER JOIN NonAtlantic
          ON Atlantic.ShipDate = NonAtlantic.ShipDate
```

There are some changes I made which I need to point out:

1. I removed the "Order By", in general, ordering should be done by whatever is consuming the data from your SQL Server, don't tax the server unnecessarily by asking it to order something when your client application can do that just as well.
2. `ORDER BY` is actually prohibited in common table expressions anyway so I'd have to move that clause to the end.
3. I have split up your query into two parts, Atlantic and NonAtlantic, and used a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to connect them, so any row that's missing in one will still appear, but it'll appear with a zero. Make sure this is what you want.
4. I use a `COALESCE` to ensure that in case there is a day with no `Atlantic Freight Charge`s and thus there is no ShipDate corresponding to that day in the `Atlantic` CTE, then it will use the date from the `NonAtlantic` CTE.

The way this works is that it connects the two queries like this:

```
ShipDate        Atlantic Freight Charge | FULL OUTER JOIN |  ShipDate        Non-Atlantic Freight Charge
01/01/2012      1.00                    |                 |  NULL            NULL
01/02/2012      1.00                    |                 |  NULL            NULL
01/03/2012      1.00                    |                 |  NULL            NULL
01/04/2012      1.00                    |                 |  01/03/2012      2.00
01/05/2012      1.00                    |                 |  01/04/2012      3.00
NULL            NULL                    |                 |  01/05/2012      4.00
NULL            NULL                    |                 |  01/06/2012      5.00
NULL            NULL                    |                 |  01/07/2012      6.00
```

And so the `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` allow me to turn that into a single set of data like this:

```
ShipDate        Atlantic Freight Charge  Non-Atlantic Freight Charge
01/01/2012      1.00                     0.00
01/02/2012      1.00                     0.00
01/03/2012      1.00                     0.00
01/04/2012      1.00                     2.00
01/05/2012      1.00                     3.00
01/05/2012      0.00                     4.00
01/06/2012      0.00                     5.00
01/07/2012      0.00                     6.00
```

### However that likely isn't the best performing solution

It's the easiest to implement, take your two queries, run both of them, and join the results. But SQL Server supports aggregate functions that let you partition the results. You may be interested in looking into the semantics of the [OVER Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) in order to learn more about how you could run your report in only a single query. I've implemented queries like that myself, but usually using `SUM`s, not `AVG`s. I would provide a possible implementation of a solution with the OVER clause, but it might be a little over-complicated and I'd be worried that I'd mess up averaging the results correctly. Actually, now that I think about it, something like this may work fine:

```
SELECT FH.ShipDate
     , AVG(CASE WHEN VendorName = 'Atlantic Trucking'  THEN FH.[Dist Freight] ELSE NULL END) AS [Atlantic Freight Charge]
     , AVG(CASE WHEN VendorName != 'Atlantic Trucking' THEN FH.[Dist Freight] ELSE NULL END) AS [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge]
  FROM dbo.vw_FreightHistory as FH
 GROUP BY ShipDate
 ORDER BY ShipDate
```

But I forget if AVG counts null rows or not.

Anyway, I hope I've both answered your question and helped you understand why your query had a problem.

Comment: Ah, I see my last solution is identical to Petio Ivanovs.

Comment: Well damn, I was not expecting such a detailed answer like yours. Thank you for breaking it down piece-by-piece and showing me exactly why it wasn't working, as well as offering those two solutions. I ended up going with the case as Petio submitted. I wasn't aware of the "COALESCE" clause, that's really nifty and useful. Much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, Martin! While I hate to sell my modesty for reputation on the site, it'd be appreciated if you could give my solution an upvote/plus one/whatever they call it just to indicate that you found it useful. Petio's solution more than suffices for your needs and I hope other people that find this post find both his answer and mine helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to upvote you, but I'll definitely come back to this post when I can. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, didn't even know that you needed reputation to upvote. Well, I hope you enjoy the StackOverflow community. :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you expect to appear in the single column if more than one row is returned?

If you want the *total* of charges, use `SUM()` around your multiple-row-returning subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FH.ShipDate, AVG(FH.[Dist Freight]) AS [Atlantic Freight Charge], 
SUM(SELECT DISTINCT [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge]
  FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT FH.ShipDate, AVG(FH.[Dist Freight]) AS [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge]
        FROM dbo.vw_FreightHistory AS FH
        WHERE VendorName != 'Atlantic Trucking'
        GROUP BY ShipDate, VendorName) AS [Non-Atlantic Freight Charge]))
FROM dbo.vw_FreightHistory as FH
WHERE VendorName = 'Atlantic Trucking'
GROUP BY ShipDate, VendorName
ORDER BY ShipDate
```